# Can cycles render motionblur and dof at the same time in 2.80?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, depth-of-field

I'm trying to wrap my head around this. I've got a simple scene with some falling cubes which I'd like to render in cycles. When I activate motion-blur, it renders with motion-blur without a problem. However, I'd like some nice DoF in there as well. As soon as I turn that on. DoF renders, but motion-blur is gone. I know there are tricks to do it all in comp, although imho, there's not a proper solution to really nail motion-blur and DoF in comp. (motionvectors can't have dof and z-depth can't have motionblur..)
Is cycles capable of rendering motionblur and dof at the same time in 2.8?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Cycles is capable of rendering both at the same time. Make sure that the DoF doesn't mask the motion blur though. If the object is out of focus you may not see the motion blur. The strength of the motion blur depends on the shutter speed and how fast the movement is.

[image: Render]

[image: Motion Blur Settings]

[image: DoF Settings]

The following link has a small example project that shows both effects in action. It was created and tested using the official release of Blender 2.8.

[image]